# React - passing ref to parent

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I am trying to think the react way but I can't find a solution on how to invoke the `.submit()` method of the form component.

I have a *material-ui* Dialog where I have to pass the buttons via actions property. From this action component, I would like to invoke the `.submit()` method of the Form component, which is a child of the dialog.

Do I have to pass the `formRef` up to the Dialog to pass it then to the Actions, and how would I do that? Or is there any ***React way*** I am missing out on?

```jsx
class FormDialog extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <Dialog actions={<Actions />} >
                <Form />
            </Dialog>
        )
    }
}

const Actions = (props) => {
    return (
        <FlatButton
            label="Submit"
            onTouchTap={() => formRef.submit()}
        />
    )
} 

const Form = () => {
    let formRef;
    return (
        <AutoForm 
            ref={ref => formRef = ref}
            onSubmit={doc => db.save(doc)} 
            >
        </AutoForm>
    )
}
```

Comment: What you can do is, create a method in the top component (where you'll invoke it) and then pass it as a prop down to Form.

You may want to take a look at Redux. http://redux.js.org/

Comment: @jhack Why redux? You can pass prop callbacks without Redux...

Answer (score 2):

Any buttons inside a form that submit the form should be `type="submit"`, and clicking on any of them will trigger the `<form />`'s `onSubmit` handler. There's no need to pass around a reference.

There's a few React-way notes here:

- If you have to pass things "up" and then back "down" a component tree, you're probably not approaching the problem correctly.
- Components should never call methods on other components.
- Unless you really know when they're needed, refs to DOM elements should only be referenced inside the component owning the ref.

Comment: Can you ellaborate on this - `Components should never call methods on other components.` 
What about call back functions?

Comment: Passing callbacks through props is a fine and useful pattern. But a parent doing something like `childComponet.setState()` or a child doing `parentComponent.submit()` is not good

Comment: Aight. How about the above question? Is there any way we can provide a solution through a callback function?

Comment: It's a bit hard to trace what you're asking, but in general the easiest way to deal with passing things "up" and "back down" the component tree is to move that thing (a callback function) into a parent component that knows about both children